# gcloud compute: configure firewall for external traffic

Tags: sockets, networking, go, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am attempting to configure my google cloud instance to allow external traffic so I can set up a web socket; however despite adding a rule for all external TCP/IP traffic, I can't access it.  My rules are:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
NAME              NETWORK SRC_RANGES RULES   SRC_TAGS TARGET_TAGS
default-allow-ssh default 0.0.0.0/0  tcp:22
external-traffic  default 0.0.0.0/0  tcp,udp


gcloud compute instances list
NAME      ZONE          MACHINE_TYPE  PREEMPTIBLE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
pi-server us-central1-a n1-standard-1             **.***.*.*  **.***.***.*** RUNNING
```

I have configured this as a static IP (this is displayed in my cloud dashboard):

```
Name               External Address Region      Type    In use by
crypto-iris-******  **.***.***.***  us-central1 Static  VM instance my_instance_name (Zone a)
```

I also have some Go client/server web socket code that works perfectly on my computer using localhost:8080 as address. So, my question is: can I simply replace localhost with the external static IP of my instance under these rules?

My client makes use of  `"github.com/gorilla/websocket"` on port 8080. Output of client locally is:

```
connecting to ws://23.251.148.133:8080/echo
dial:dial tcp 23.251.148.133:8080: getsockopt: operation timed out
exit status 1
```

Code upon request, if anyone wants to see it.

Comment: How did you create the "external-traffic" firewall rule? I think you might have to pass in a specific port.

For websockets on port 8080, this might work:
gcloud compute firewall-rules create websocket --allow tcp:8080

Answer (score 2):

Problem: my golang/gorilla server was hosting on `localhost:8080`. I changed it to `0.0.0.0:8080`.  Smooth sailing after that.

See following post about this, but basically the server was listening to the local loopback address (available only to local machine) instead of the outside world.

https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1

Comment: Changing to 0.0.0.0:8080 worked for me! Thank you so much for this.